# How do I perform a full reinstallation of pip and pip3?

Tags: package-management, python, pip

I want out of my computer what everyone else wants: for it to work properly.

Now on to the problem: I was trying to install a package via **pip3** when I got a message indicating that I was using an outdated version of **pip3**.  I tried installing the new version using `pip install --upgrade pip`.  Long story short, my computer's managed to get itself stuck using **pip**V8, which is more than 10 versions behind where it needs to be.  This is a problem with both **pip** and **pip3**.

Now, usually I'd be able to fix this on my own, but it seems to me that there's still some hidden statefulness from either my system's packages, existing files, or **pip**'s own cache that prevents me from performing a complete removal and re-installation (because I'm not going to try to perform an upgrade at this point).

What must I do in order to remove **pip** and **pip3** completely from my system, and subsequently install their fully up-to-date versions?

Answer (score 1):

To completely remove and reinstall pip and pip3 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt purge python-pip python3-pip  
sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip  
pip uninstall --user pip  
pip3 uninstall --user pip3
```

Removing a package removes all packaged data, but leaves usually           small (modified) user configuration files behind, in case the           remove was an accident. Just issuing an installation request for           the accidentally removed package will restore its function as           before in that case. On the other hand you can get rid of these           leftovers by calling `purge` even on already removed packages. Note           that this does not affect any data or configuration stored in your           home directory.

Comment: I have already tried purging the packages multiple times using **aptitude**.  Unfortunately this does not work since there are indeed files in my user directory created by **pip** and **pip3** which need to be removed.  This probably should've been noticable from my question regarding the `pip install --upgrade pip` part.  Thus, I'm just going to try `rm -rf`ing things manually again and pray that it works.

Comment: So did it worked?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that since I'd been using `sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip`, there was a folder named `/root/.cache/pip/` that I needed to delete.

**EDIT:**

I have managed to fix an issue with installing the new version of `pip` using [an answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210269/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-when-running-pip-version-command-in-windo).  I had another issue after that with `pip3` breaking based upon some file permission issues, but I've fixed that as well.  The problem is completely resolved now.